# Selecting an element with the closest common ancestor

Tags: jquery

I need to find a way to select a DOM element that shares the closest common ancestor with a given element.

Here's what I mean:

```
<div class="grandparent">
   <span class="match not-this-one">
   <div class="parent">
      <span class="match this-one">
      <div class="container">
         <span class="me">
      </div>
</div>
```

I want something that does this:

```
$('.me').closestCousin('match'); selects <span class="match this-one">
```

closest() and parent() select ancestors, but don't look for cousin elements.

Comment: Missing closing `</span>` tags at `html` at Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.closest()` with selector `:not(.me)` to exclude current element from being matched by `.closest()`; `siblings()` with selector `.match`

```js
$(".me").closest(":not(.me)").siblings(".match").addClass("matched")
```

```css
.matched {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="grandparent">
   <span class="match not-this-one">not-this-one</span>
   <div class="parent">
      <span class="match this-one">match this-one</span>
      <div class="container">
         <span class="me">me</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not going to work if the closest one is outside the current element's parent.

Comment: @dave _"That's not going to work if the closest one is outside the current element's parent."_  That would be outside of scope of requirement described at original Question  _"to select a DOM element that shares the closest common ancestor with a given element"_ where the matched element is a sibling of parent of `.me`

Comment: You're right. I misread the question. I thought he wanted to continue searching up the tree until he found a match.

Comment: @dave Had to re-read original Question a couple of occasions; requirement could have perhaps been made clearer with term "sibling" being substituted for "cousin", though first sentence at OP at "closest common ancestor" provided guidance, here, for what expected result appeared to be.

Comment: This does not work when the next element `.match` is not a sibling of the parent (but of grandparent, or parent of gradparent, or ...).

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to write a recursive function that combines the use of [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to find your *closest cousin*.

**Edit:** I misunderstood the question. This solution searches up the tree to find the closest target, and as a byproduct of its implementation will also find siblings to the original element.

```js
function closestCousin(me, target) {
  var cousin = me.prev(target);
  if (cousin.length) {
    return cousin;
  } else {
    var parent = me.parent();
    if (parent.length) {
      return closestCousin(parent, target);
    } else {
      return parent;  
    }
  }
}

var me = $(".me");
closestCousin(me, ".match").css("color", "red");
closestCousin(me, ".match2").css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grandparent">
   <span class="match match2 not-this-one">Don't Match</span>
   <div class="parent">
      <span class="match this-one">Match</span>
      <div class="container">
         <span class="me">Me</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Selects `.not-this-one` if `<span class="match this-one">Match</span>` is placed below `.container` in `html` https://jsfiddle.net/2yn3vdzy/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
    $('.me').closest('.match');

But it only goes up the DOM tree. If that's what you need,

Comment: That's not going to return any results

Answer (score 0):

`$('.me').closest(':has(.match)').find('.match')`

Selects the closest common ancestor (the closest element containing a descendant with matching class). And then selects the matching descendant(s).
The search is for **any** descentants, not children only!

- e1

  - .match two
  - e2

    - e3

      - .match one
  - e2b

    - .me

*.match one* would be found here.

to get *.match two* in above case, run:

`$('.me').parents().children('.match').first()`

select all ancestors (closest listed first), then get their children matching the criteria. Take the 1st one since this is the closest one.